# Connect to host by name using a Linksys wrt54g as my router and dhcp server

Tags: router, dns, dhcp

I have a Linksys WRT54G router at my house.

How do I enable/perform connect-by-name on my network (like "kitchen" and "musicbox") on Windows XP, Linux (Ubuntu and CentOS), and Mac clients?

Sometimes it seems to work "on its own", but normally I have to go by IP address - which is a bit of a pain to remember properly.

I'd also like to ***NOT*** use the `/etc/hosts` route and have to maintain all of them by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the answer you are looking for but this is exactly what a domain server can easily accomplish for you. So if your linux machine is always on, you could use it to assign dhcp for the network instead of the router. So then it can take the computer name and assign it a dns entry. An example could be found [here](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch08_:_Configuring_the_DHCP_Server). But you are better off going to your distro's website and find documentation on it.

Comment: I may go for setting-up a VM running something like m0n0wall and use it as my firewall/router/etc. Thanks for this idea.

Comment: Heh I personally love m0n0wall. A friend and I both use it for our personal routers.

Answer (score 1):

You can try loading an 3rd party firmware onto your router such as [Tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato) or [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index).  Both support this feature out of the box.

Comment: not possible by default, eh? shame :-\